# Como mapear uma string json para outra string json?

Tags: c#, json, conversão-de-tipo

Existe alguma forma de fazer um maper de ums string json para outra string json?

O objetivo e pegar o valor de uma propriedade do json e setar em outra propriedade do outro json.

Exe;

Tenho o json.

```
{
    "codigo":0,
    "descricao":"string",
    "limiteDiario":0,
    "limiteMensal":0,
    "agencia":0,
    "conta":0,
    "codigoDoProduto":0,
    "entidadePrincipal":{
        "codigo":0,
        "tipo":"string",
        "pessoa":{
            "codigo":0,
            "nome":"string",
            "documento":{
                "codigo":0,
                "numero":"string",
                "dataDeEmissao":"2018-04-05T19:14:32.279Z",
                "orgaoEmissor":"string",
                "tipoDeDocumento":0
            },
            "tipoDePessoa":0,
            "situacao":0
        }
    }
}
```

E quero pegar o valor do campo ***descricao*** para setar no campo ***descricao*** de outro json. o campo ***tipo*** no **tipoDeControle** e assim por diante.

```
{
    "codigo":0,
    "descricao":"string",
    "parametros":{
        "codigo":0,
        "tipoDeControle":0,
        "numero":0,
        "orgaoEmissor":"string",
        "tipoDePessoa":0
    }
}
```

Vi que tem algumas bibliotecas como https://github.com/joelvh/json2json e https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-mapper, mas não entendi bem como usar.

Comment: como você quer fazer usando `c#` me parece mais fácil converter o Json para objeto usando a classe `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` e usar um mapper em `C#`, como o https://automapper.org/ para mapear para outro objeto com propriedades com nomes semelhantes

Comment: @RicardoPontual, seria legal, mas isso será montando em um gateway  e será vários json que vai vim, minha ideia é criar Templates para fazer isso para cada json...se for usar o automapper teria que criar os modelos para todos os json.